# How to pull specific remote into current branch in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Using built in Git in Visual Studio Code, I do not see a way to pull a specified remote branch into my current branch. Can I do this?

Example: I am working on branch `myBranch` and changes were merged into `master` on the remote. I want to pull the changes from `master` into my current `myBranch`

Comment: Do you still need to add the remote to your Git repo as well, or is this just about pulling the changes into your current branch?

Comment: Just pulling changes into current branch from a different branch

Comment: Under Source control three dots, pull push,  ftech from all. Or use the new answer below to auto enable it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's currently a built-in way to do this, but I've found an extension for it: [Git: Pull - Remote/Branch Specified](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samschneller.git-pull-upstream)

It adds a command with the same name, which when invoked, prompts you for the name of the remote and remote branch to pull from:

[image]

Comment: This answer is now outdated. Use "pull from" instead (see answer below)

Comment: This answer is no longer the best answer -1

Answer (score 20):

I am using Version 1.30.1 (1.30.1) and now it has build-in way to do this.

[image]

Comment: one step that wasn't so clear to me was you needed to drill down to get to the branches. So after choosing Pull, Push then choosing Pull from..., you need to choose "origin"  then your branches would appear.

Comment: Does this not pull that remote branch into whatever branch you are currently on locally? Or does it checkout to this as a new branch locally too?

Comment: There are no settings for this that I can find so this is all you get: The current working branch is where it pulls to, it doesn't have an option to select where to pull to, only where to pull from. **Before you pull** check your active branch in cs code, thats where the pull is going to. It doesnt give a warning or a confirmation.

Comment: No longer the best answer. Basically VS isn't fetching remotes and the answer below shows you how to enable that by default. The other way is to just manually fetch all remotes... but you don't need to do that in full Visual Studio so its was a bit confusing for me

Comment: I had to do "Fetch from all remotes" to get the branch to show up to then pull.

Answer (score 13):

Finally i solve it this way

```
File->Preferences->Settings->User (Tab)-> Extentions ->git-> Autofeatch(set checkbox to true)
```

[image]

Now you will able to see remote branches in `source control` branches options

Comment:  This should be the accepted answer. ✔✅ Also, why is this not default. It in in full Visual Studio. Thank you so much for this!